# Adding labels to Google Cloud Functions trigger topic while deploying functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am able to set labels to google cloud functions using gcloud cli tool. However, I want to set labels to the trigger topic as well while I deploy the function.

How to do that?

```
gcloud functions deploy [PARAMETERS] --update-labels lables-key=label-value --trigger-topic=a.simple.pubsub.topic
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You can manage the pubsub labels with the gcloud tools with the following:

- `gcloud pubsub topics update mytopic --update-labels=KEY1=VAL1,KEY2=VAL2`

Note  from the pub/sub documentation:

> Pub/Sub resources do not inherit labels from each other. You would set the same label on both the topic and the subscription in order to associate them with each other.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/update

**Original**

That appears to be the correct syntax when declaring them, ensure that you are setting the topic correctly as a string value and there are no typos.
`labels` vs `lables`

`gcloud functions deploy subscribe --trigger-topic MY_TOPIC --runtime RUNTIME`

> The name of the Pub/Sub topic to which the function is subscribed. If the topic doesn't exist, it is created during deployment.

Reference:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#deploying_your_function
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--trigger-topic

Comment: I thought I was clear on the question. I have no issue with trigger topic creation. I just want  the labels I set for cloud functions to be set for cloud pub sub trigger topic that's created as well.  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--update-labels following this sets label only on Cloud function